# Restricting POST create operations based on content types

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to set up my Rails controller to only perform a create action if the request has a JavaScript or xml payload.  I don't want HTML form submits to trigger a create.  Ideally, attempting to do so would send you to an page explaining that you can't do that.

I think one solution would be to put a `prepend_before_filter` on the controller that would check the content_type and accept headers of the request.

But is there a cleaner or more common way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think one solution would be to put a
>   `prepend_before_filter` on the
>   controller that would check the
>   content_type and accept headers of the
>   request.

I think you've got the right idea here.

Answer (score 0):

My way would be to put your function in the model by using the before_create method